# what is a relay descriptor

Tags: relays

What is a relay descriptor? Where is it used?I found this on running a python code to launch Tor:

50%: Loading relay descriptors

51%: Loading relay descriptors

53%: Loading relay descriptors

55%: Loading relay descriptors

56%: Loading relay descriptors

Answer (score 2):

Information that relays send to clients about themselves.

https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/mirror_mirror_on_the_wall.html

Answer (score 1):

Is it helpful and useful information about p2p Tor Network.

See here,

```
# cat /var/lib/tor/cached-descriptors | grep -i ^finger  | sort -u | wc
   7184   79024  445408
```

7184 descriptors for me.

Each descriptor contain full information about relay, IP Address, fingerprint of public key, platform, everything what you are need to connect to the Tor network through this relay.

See, for example:

```
@downloaded-at 2014-07-29 19:02:18
@source "76.73.17.194"
router Survivor2007 89.169.165.233 8443 0 853
platform Tor 0.2.4.21 on Linux
protocols Link 1 2 Circuit 1
published 2014-07-29 17:23:46
fingerprint 2B49 996F 18E6 B9CB 08A7 BBDF B28F 9891 72F9 1BA7
uptime 2107519
bandwidth 3072000 3584000 1297084
extra-info-digest F2BCBC3D5C858CE64A1CE84FDB544A3349BB901F
onion-key
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBAMh/jMVXHP+NScqErH/v2VmFrIzfsNr5PG91hvWngwJkFEVG/870zkof
3YDJhpV4oo4ku1rKc2DlaQRCJCEDLSJIF3Ie3IVks9BW1YHmOlkyWrLmqvDMTNUt
BXTIsQJiSdHM2GQtUSOlijaXWh05Ax+zD6HnfNlEq84+OzTsLs+3AgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
signing-key
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBALYVg7wnmrkSxoZ/xQB1thhu354sCw0u91KHKvXCy12N1iCvNi+VY2eA
3UzUB1wHbzyU4/6IAA8TWx0vCQrRbkSB7dr1v/64HqFIajFiIJYMvld8TzpSa/6J
h99irINd0uYUyHXfDosVFKcKYOcf6MVmZRuwEkI5U6pUTW7hCaP1AgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
hidden-service-dir
contact Survivor2007 <survivor2007@gmail.com>
ntor-onion-key FyW6tx+T3r5+U4VUo98Cq4hzPAC7riEOqXPc8dFTm04=
reject *:*
```

This is just a relay, not an exit, because `reject *:*`. Contact of relay owner: `Survivor2007 <survivor2007@gmail.com>`.

`uptime 2107519` - which is 24 days, 9:25:19

`platform Tor 0.2.4.21 on Linux`

etc.

See another my answer: [What is the best Way To Run Tor (Operating Systems)?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/what-is-the-best-way-to-run-tor-operating-systems/3743#3743)